# How to display a confirmation message in Tapestry5?

Tags: java, tapestry

I am developing a website as part of my final year project and I want to display a message which confirms that an email has been sent.

I know how to display custom error messages on a form i.e. You cannot go any further until the following errors are fixed : login name not known!

I want to display a message which will say: your email has been sent! after I send an email. 
I have been told that I should display this message through the flash.

I am unsure on how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you'd like to display a message which is not a form error in Tapestry... okay. But what is the role of Flash in your setup?

Comment: @Henning: Yes i would like to display a message that says your email has been sent similar to fro e.g. gmail, when your email has been sent. I have never used flash before, I am just wondering what is the best way to display such a message in tapestry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to show a conditional message on the page displayed when the message was sent, like:

```
<span t:type="If" t:test="messageSent">Your message was sent.</span>
```

Page class snippet:

```
@Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
private boolean messageSent;


public boolean isMessageSent() {
    return this.messageSent;
}

@OnEvent(EventConstants.SUCCESS)
void onSendMessage() {
    ...
    this.messageSent = true;
}
```

If you have other places in your code where you'd like to display messages, or if you'd like to do some fancy AJAX, creating a messages component to add to your layout might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Since Tapestry 5.3 you can use the Alerts component.

Template:

```
<t:alerts />
```

Page class:

```
@Inject
private AlertManager alertManager;

@OnEvent(EventConstants.SUCCESS)
void onSendMessage() {
     ...
     this.alertManager.success("Your message was sent.");
}
```

Jumpstart has an example of it. You can play around with it at http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/examples/component/alerts